# How to use explorer like functions in Recycle Bin itself?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, data-recovery, ntfs

I have a large folder in the Recycle Bin on Windows 7 Ultimate Edition. I cannot restore that folder (too big) but I want to be able to **explore** it; like open it so I can restore only the files I want.

QTTabBar isn't working, and I cannot find Python or PowerShell utilities that parse NTFS as I want. So how can I explore a folder inside the Recycle Bin only?

It will be awesome if i can view the restore path metadata of each file.

Comment: If the files were deleted from C: drive then those were stored in `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` folder which is a hidden folder.

Comment: You can't......